# $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, nestjs, aggregate

i'm trying to apply different filters along with nearby filter but user can also skip all other filter and just apply nearby filter. i'm getting the exact result if user selet tags or cuisines filter also. but when user skip both then it throws an exception. here is my code below

```
const query = [];
if (cuisines) {
  const culinaryOptions = {
    culinaryOptions: { $in: cuisines },
  };
  query.push(culinaryOptions);
}
if (tags) {
  const tag = {
    tags: { $in: tags },
  };
  query.push(tag);
}
if (nearest) {
  maxDistance = 10;
  sort = -1;
}
console.log(query);
return this.restaurantModel.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude)],
      },
      distanceField: 'distanceFromMe',
      maxDistance: maxDistance ?? 100 * METERS_PER_MILE, //!*** distance in meters ***!//
      distanceMultiplier: 1 / 1609.34,
      spherical: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: query,
    },
  },
  { $unset: ['verificationCode', 'uniqueCode'] },
  { $sort: { location: sort ?? 1 } },
]);
```

}
how to get only nearby restaurants if user skips all other filter

Comment: If you skip cuisines and tags, then nothing gets pushed into `query`, which then leads to an empty array in `$or`. Thus resulting in the error. One way to avoid that would be to only add `{$match: { $or: query, },}` in the array used in `aggregate`, when `query` isn't empty.

Comment: how to do it? can you please tell me. i'm not getting the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should generate your query, on the basis of whether something is present in the `query` or not. If nothing is there in the `query` array don't add the stage `$match`.

```
const query = [];
if (cuisines) {
  const culinaryOptions = {
    culinaryOptions: { $in: cuisines },
  };
  query.push(culinaryOptions);
}
if (tags) {
  const tag = {
    tags: { $in: tags },
  };
  query.push(tag);
}
if (nearest) {
  maxDistance = 10;
  sort = -1;
}
console.log(query);
let pipeline = [
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude)],
      },
      distanceField: 'distanceFromMe',
      maxDistance: maxDistance ?? 100 * METERS_PER_MILE, //!*** distance in meters ***!//
      distanceMultiplier: 1 / 1609.34,
      spherical: true,
    }
 }];
if (query.length > 0) {
  pipeline = [...pipeline, {
    $match: {
      $or: query,
    },
  }];  
}
pipeline = [...pipeline, { $unset: ['verificationCode', 'uniqueCode'] },
  { $sort: { location: sort ?? 1 } } ];
return this.restaurantModel.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: it's is working fine but if now i skip location it is throwing error.otherwise working perfectly fine

Comment: You can add the $geoNear stage conditionally as we are doing for $match.